# How to instruct CMake to find specific version of Curl

Tags: cmake, build, libcurl

I have built Curl from source and it's installed in `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so`

I am now trying to instruct CMake to statically link this version with my application (if dynamic is easier, that's fine).

From other Stackoverflow questions I tried this:

```
option(CURL_STATICLIB "Set to ON to build libcurl with static linking."  ON)
option(LIBCURL_ENABLE "Enable or disable the requirement of libcurl" ON)

set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl") 
set(CURL_PATH "/usr/local/lib")

find_library(LIB_CURL NAMES libcurl PATHS ${CURL_PATH})

include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(STATUS "LIB_CURL: " ${LIB_CURL})

add_definitions(-DCURL_STATICLIB)
target_link_libraries(my_project PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

but it cannot find `libcurl.so`:

```
LIB_CURL: LIB_CURL-NOTFOUND
```

(My CMake knowledge is basic, any additional tips to improve the above are welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
option(CURL_STATICLIB "Set to ON to build libcurl with static linking."  ON)
option(LIBCURL_ENABLE "Enable or disable the requirement of libcurl" ON)
```

`option` is used wrongly. curl is not configured in that CMakeLists, therefore `option` should be removed.

Try

```
find_library(LIB_CURL NAMES curl PATHS ${CURL_PATH})
```

It's unclear, you define `-DCURL_STATICLIB`  but look for `libcurl.so`

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I also realized I had to change my target_link_libraries from CURL_LIBRARIES to CURL_LIBRARY.